# How to pass a parameter in function of type string if it also requires an object type param?

Tags: c#, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have function handler

```
namespace AWSLambda2
{

    public class input
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Function
    {
        public string FunctionHandler(string data, input input)
        {   
            return input.name?.ToUpper()+", "+input.email?.ToUpper()+", "+data; 
        }
    }
}
```

It takes a string type param and input of object type. Fine.

For object type I can pass:

```
{
    "name":"test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
}
```

but it throws an error because I have to pass data param too. How to pass that while passing a JSON payload for POST request using POSTMAN or Swagger.

Comment: Where did you used `context` argument?

Comment: no where, that comes by default with lambda function... it doesn't need to be passed if you don't need to.

Comment: `public class input` should be `public class Input` Classes are capitalised

Comment: @Matt: thanks but that's not the problem here. Please read the questions

Comment: It's one of the problems, might not be the problem.

Comment: Set `data` to `String.Empty` by default eg `public string FunctionHandler(input input, string data = String.Empty)`

Comment: @Matt: yes, not the one I asked the solution for

Comment: @Haldo: not working

Comment: @azureboy ho it is not working? Any specific errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [AWS Lambda Function Handler in C#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html)

> You define a Lambda function handler as an instance or static method
>   in a class. If you want access to the Lambda context object, it is
>   available by defining a method parameter of type ILambdaContext, an
>   interface you can use to access information about the current
>   execution, such as the name of the current function, the memory limit,
>   execution time remaining, and logging.
>
> ```
> returnType handler-name(inputType input, ILambdaContext context) {
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> In the syntax, note the following:
>
> - `inputType` – **The first handler parameter is the input to the handler**,
>     which can be event data (published by an event source) or custom input
>     that you provide such as a string or any custom data object.
> - `returnType` – If you plan to invoke the Lambda function synchronously
>     (using the RequestResponse invocation type), you can return the output
>     of your function using any of the supported data types. For example,
>     if you use a Lambda function as a mobile application backend, you are
>     invoking it synchronously. Your output data type will be serialized
>     into JSON.
>     If you plan to invoke the Lambda function asynchronously (using the
>     Event invocation type), the returnType should be void. For example, if
>     you use AWS Lambda with event sources such as Amazon S3 or Amazon SNS,
>     these event sources invoke the Lambda function using the Event
>     invocation type.

According to  [Working with Lambda Functions : Programming Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model-v2.html)

> You write code for your Lambda function in one of the languages AWS Lambda supports. ***Regardless of the language you choose, there is a common pattern to writing code for a Lambda function*** that includes the following core concepts:
>
> - **Handler** – Handler is the function AWS Lambda calls to start execution of your Lambda function. You identify the handler when you create your Lambda function. When a Lambda function is invoked, AWS Lambda starts executing your code by calling the handler function. ***AWS Lambda passes any event data to this handler as the first parameter***. Your handler should process the incoming event data and may invoke any other functions/methods in your code.
> - **The context object and how it interacts with Lambda at runtime** – ***AWS Lambda also passes a  context  object to the handler function, as the second parameter***. Via this context object your code can interact with AWS Lambda. For example, your code can find the execution time remaining before AWS Lambda terminates your Lambda function.
>     In addition, for languages such as Node.js, there is an asynchronous platform that uses callbacks. AWS Lambda provides additional methods on this context object. You use these context object methods to tell AWS Lambda to terminate your Lambda function and optionally return values to the caller.
>
> .....

*emphasis mine.*

So to answer your title

> How to pass a parameter in function of type string if it also requires an object type param?

Short Answer: **You can't**

I suggest creating a specific model to hold the desired data

```
public class SampleClass {
    public string data { get; set; }
    public Input input { get; set; }
}
```

And using that for the function input

```
namespace AWSLambda2 {

    public class Input {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Function {
        public string FunctionHandler(SampleClass input) {
            var data = input.data;
            var user = input.input;
            return user.name?.ToUpper()+", "+user.email?.ToUpper()+", "+data; 
        }
    }
}
```

Similar to how it is shown in samples provided

https://github.com/guitarrapc/AWSLambdaCSharpIntroduction/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you have a DTO to hold both the data like below and have your handler accepts that type `public string FunctionHandler(MyModel model)`

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string Data {get; set;}
  public Input Input {get; set;}
}
```

I see, then have the extra data passed through query string and define your Api handler as such like

```
public string FunctionHandler([FromQuery]string data, [FromBody]input input)
```

Comment: thanks and yes i tired that but I am testing it the other way, like I described in the question.

Comment: you can not do that in lambda function but in webapi